# c, greatest integer less than k

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

Given a number and a binary tree, find the greatest number in the node less than k.

The function I used looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//A binary tree with a pointer to the left and right child
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

// function to allocate new node
struct node* newNode(int data)
{
    struct node* node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    node->data = data;
    node->left = node->right = NULL;
    return (node);
}

int findNum (struct node* root, int K)
{
    int val = K;

    while( root )
        if( root->data >= K )
            root = root->left;
        else{
            val = root->data;
            root = root->right;
        }

    return val;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root = newNode(9);
    root->left = newNode(13);
    root->right = newNode(10);
    root->right->right= newNode(20);
    root->left->left  = newNode(8);
    root->left->right = newNode(4);
    root->right->right->left = newNode(3);
    root->right->right->right = newNode(18);

    printf("%d", findNum(root,21));
    return 0;
}
```

The output in this case should have been 20, but it outputs 18. The program isn't working, what have I done wrong?

Comment: I meant 18, i updated the question

Comment: You need to step through the code in your debugger to see what's going on - this will be much more productive then asking other people to debug your code for you.

Comment: IS the function to find the greatest number less than k correct?

Comment: You won't know until you debug your code.

Comment: Your code requires ordered binary tree. In ordered binary tree, (aNode->data)<(aNode->right->data) if (aNode->right) != NULL, and (aNode->data)>(aNode->left->data) if (aNode->left) != NULL. You may made some mistake in main routine.

Comment: It says debugger finished with status 0.

Comment: You need to *single-step through the code* in your debugger in order to understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

From the code in `main()` that builds the tree, your tree looks like:

```
     9
    / \
   13 10
  /\    \
 8  4   20
        /\
       3  18
```

This is clearly *not* a properly structured binary search tree, it doesn't uphold the invariant that nodes to the left of a node should be less than their parent and so on. Thus, your search code, which assumes a binary search tree, won't work.

You can of course fix the initialization code, but you can also consider actually implementing `insert()` for a binary search tree, so you can simplify the code in `main()`.

Answer (score 0):

why you expect another value, when you overwrite val variable all time without any condition:

```
while( root )
        if( root->data >= K )
            root = root->left;
        else{
            val = root->data;
            root = root->right;
        }
```

in your case, the if (root->data >= K) is never meet so you go to else statement, where you just write value to val variable and go to another "right-node", so you will have always the last value which is in right node.

Answer (score 0):

`static int result = INT.MIN;void foo (Node root, int k){

if(root == null) return;

if( root.value

foo(root.left);
foo(root.right);
}`